# on click and fastclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, fastclick

I have a lightbox function in a new site that works just fine on my desktop but on an ipad the clicks have a serious lag in interation. I added "fastclick" to the project but doesnt seem to help a lot. Here is what I have if anyone sees something wrong with the code

js

```
$('a[data-ocular]').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     //some more code 
}

$('#galleryPrev').off().on( "click", function() {

     currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex) - 1;
     updateImage(currentImageIndex); 

 });
```

fastclick init at before `</body>` on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
          FastClick.attach(document.body);
     });
</script?>
```

Comment: Did you put fastclick in a `script` tag somewhere too?

Comment: just edited to my question, but yes at the end of the page @JoshBeam

Comment: no, I mean, did you load the fastclick module into the page before invoking it? For example, you need `<script src="where/fastclick/is/fastclick.js"></script>`. And then later you call `FastClick.attach()`.

Comment: Ya, its loaded in the page before I call it. In the docs I didnt see the `fastclick.attach()` , it said to use `$(function() { FastClick.attach(document.body); });` correct? Do I need to add `touchEnd` or `touchStart` on my click event?

Comment: I just wrote `FastClick.attach()` as shorthand for the method you were calling, but yes, you are correct. Can you post the whole HTML document where you're doing this? I use `FastClick` too, and the way you're invoking it looks correct (yes, you can use the `click` event, you don't need `touch`), so that tells me something else strange is going on.

Comment: Unfortunatlwy the page is pretty long so cant post the whole thing. Should I init fastClick very last?

Comment: Yes. Right before the closing `</body>` tag. Try posting the code in a JSFiddle. Can't help if I can't see all the code.